# First call to malloc after launching thread takes very long

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, pthreads, dynamic-memory-allocation

First, I'll state that I am unable to replicate the behavior with an example program. It is a bit difficult as I'm not exactly sure what is causing the issue.

I've provided some code to give a sort of mental map of what I'm trying to describe. Essentially, as described in the title, we see that the first call a thread makes to malloc with a size of >= 1KB takes a very long time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>


using namespace std::chrono;


class myClass {
public:
    myClass();
    void someFunction();
};

myClass::myClass() {;}

void myClass::someFunction() {
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    int *arr1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    int *arr2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000);

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    duration<double, std::milli> time_span1 = t2 - t1;
    duration<double, std::milli> time_span2 = t3 - t2;

    std::cout << "first alloc took" << time_span1.count() << "milliseconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "second alloc took" << time_span2.count() << "milliseconds" << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    myClass obj1;


    std::vector<std::thread> ThreadManager(1);

    ThreadManager[0] = std::thread(&myClass::someFunction, obj1);

    ThreadManager[0].join();
}
```

Again, the issue is not present in this example. This example shows that the first malloc in the launched thread takes longer than the second. However, on my machine, the execution of the first malloc takes about 0.05 milliseconds which is not a concern for me. The "speedup" of the second call can easily be attributed to something like ILP.

In the project I'm working on, the execution time of the first malloc is much worse (5-10ms). This occurs only in the first call to malloc after launching a thread, provided the amount of memory requested is not negligible (>= ~1KB). I have noticed the issue is present when launching only one thread (as in the example code), so it does not seem to be a synchronization issue. The issue could be related to fragmentation, but if I request the same amount of memory right before launching the thread, we see no performance issue. Additionally, most allocations in the project are done via allocators that request large chunks at a time, which I believe should reduce the probability of a fragmentation problem. Moreover, I have tested on multiple inputs to the main program, and the set of inputs on which the issue occurs is deterministic -- which implies to me that it is not related to complexities of runtime. I should mention that the project I'm working on is moderately sized (10s of thousands of lines), and the callable to the std::thread belongs to a class that is relatively large.

Essentially, I do not know what could be causing this problem, and am wondering if anyone has seen something like this before -- and if so, how they fixed it :)

EDIT:
After further investigation, the performance bug is at least indirectly related to synchronization. `malloc` uses a number of arenas to handle multiple synchronous calls. The number of these arenas can be changed via a call to `mallopt`. After changing the maximum number of arenas to one via `mallopt(M_ARENA_MAX, 1)`, the performance of the first call to `malloc` has returned to normal. That said, since the application is multi-threaded, I would like to make use of more arenas, and when I change the max to 2, the overhead returns (5-10ms for the first call to `malloc`). I'm wondering how increasing the number of arenas could lead to such an overhead.

Comment: *"so it does not seem to be a synchronization issue."* You need to reconsider that assumption. `main` is a thread, so even a single call to `std::thread` makes the process multithreaded, and forces `malloc` to deal with synchronization. Since I can't see what `main` does in the real program, I can only suggest putting a `sleep(2)` in `main` after the call to `std::thread` and see if that changes the behavior. You could also put the `sleep(2)` at the beginning of `someFunction` to let the dust settle before attempting the first `malloc` (just to see if that changes the behavior).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your thoughts. I should mention that similar to the example program, the thread corresponding to `main` simply calls join immediately after launching the threads. Thus, I believe it is not doing any allocation during the time the launched thread is running. As expected, issuing a sleep statement between launch and join didn't have any impact. On the other hand, when requiring the launch thread to immediately `sleep(2)` we see that there is no longer a long execution time for the first malloc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot withstand a `sleep(2)` in this part of the program (hence the initial issue with execution time). I'm wondering what dust settles during this time period, and if there's anyway I can pre-settle this dust for each thread before launching it (or better yet, avoiding dust settling altogether)

Comment: Maybe you can't use the `sleep` in the final product, and magic, bug-fixing sleeps are never a good idea, but it could be helpful in figuring out what the problem is. Once you know what the problem is, you can come up with a good solution. If you don't know what the problem is, good luck finding a solution. And if you do find a solution, how will you know?

Comment: Thanks, ill try modifying the example, but in my working project the issue occurs when launching 1 thread. Of course, the point of parallelization is to launch multiple threads simultaneously, so this will change.

Comment: @byrnesj1 Yup, I reread the question after posting and noticed that, so I deleted the comment. It's still worth trying to replicate the problem with the example, I think.

Comment: Update: Since this area is performance sensitive, I have implemented a timeout feature. When issuing `sleep(2)` immediately after thread launch, it triggered the timeout, and the memory that was supposed to be allocated by `malloc` never got used, and, as a result, the compiler likely removed the code. Accounting for the additional 2 seconds in the timeout, we see that the long `malloc` execution time is actually still present (contrary to what I said previously)

Comment: A useful answer is unlikely, since you posted code that you describe as representative but doesn't reproduce the problem. That suggests code you haven't shown is implicated. In general terms, book-keeping associated with creating/starting threads can - depending on OS - introduce delays/conflicts when accessing other resources, including memory.  Also, C functions (like `malloc()`) may be unaware of C++ threading so not play well.  One strategy may be to create a thread pool during program startup and recycle threads as needed rather than starting threads in response to (say) user actions.

Answer (score 2):

It may or may not be a synchronization issue. The language implementation of malloc may be managing per-thread or per-processor free lists or there may be a single memory pool which may require synchronization. So, not understanding what the remaining code (indeed, the whole app and runtime) does will leads to speculation.

At the same time, the user-mode memory manager does two things: One is making sure the operating system allocates (aka "makes valid") a portion of the virtual address space and the second is to subdivide that portion in response to malloc() calls.

So, it is conceivable (speculation) that the first call to malloc requests virtual address space from the OS. Not a cheap call.  The second call may simply return pointers into space that was returned by the OS, making it much faster.

Again, speculation.

Comment: So, after much more investigation, I have found that the culprit is actually the arena allocators within malloc (so it does seem to be at least indirectly related to syncrhonization). When I reduce the number of arenas to 1 via `mallopt(M_ARENA_MAX, 1);` I am seeing no malloc performance issue across all inputs when launching just one thread, however when I increase the number of arenas to 2 or more, the original problem returned (5-10ms malloc delay). Do you have any idea why increasing the number of arenas would result in such an overhead?

Comment: Without actually looking at the code, I'm guessing. Sorry!

Comment: Yes I understand this was a difficult question to answer, and I appreciate your input. The comment was for future viewers that are looking to solve their own problems